# HTML Mail - Outlook - After Loading Images - Layout broken

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, newsletter

i have a problem with html mails and outlook. If i send the newsletter and open it in outlook there are no images, thats ok. And the table layout looks alright. Then, i download the images and it looks perfect. The pictures/images fittig exact in cells. And then, 1  sec later the layout is broken. Im using only inline css, and tables. The images width and height are right, no javascript. I dont get it.

Comment: Share the code or make a simple example that breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If this HTML code is generated through Photoshop/Dreamweaver, or if you are using `colspan` or `rowspan` then this indeed is a common effect. My solution was always nest tables in tables, other than go the other way and use `rowspan`/`colspan`.

Hope it helps and also a bit of code examples or origin(generating software) won't hurt.